# How to add a button in Xamarin.Forms?

Tags: android, xamarin, xamarin.forms

I'm new to Xamarin.
Could you write me the code for adding a button in Xamarin.Forms?

Comment: Are you using XAML or do you want to add via C# code ?

Comment: I try to add via C# code.

Comment: Why down vote ? Could you explain ?

Comment: Perhaps because the solution is pretty straight-forward and could be found out easily from Xamarin's documentation.

Comment: But I'm not so good at English, thats why I ask here sometimes.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
public class App : Application
{
    public App ()
    {
        // The root page of your application
        MainPage =new ContentPage{
            Content= new Button{Text="Hello World",BackgroundColor=Color.Black,HorizontalOptions=LayoutOptions.Center,VerticalOptions=LayoutOptions.Center,TextColor=Color.White}
        };
    }


}
```

Above snippet will create a Page with a Button having text `Hello World` centered horizontally and vertically in the page and set it as the LaunchPage of the application. This is an example of how you can have button programmatically.

Answer (score 2):

Maybe you should get started with this introduction. It explains how get started with Xamarin forms.

https://developer.xamarin.com/guides/xamarin-forms/getting-started/introduction-to-xamarin-forms/

Answer (score 1):

There is also the [Xamarin forms quick start](https://developer.xamarin.com/guides/xamarin-forms/getting-started/hello-xamarin-forms/quickstart/) which runs through an example that adds buttons to the UI.

From example :

xaml:

```
<Button x:Name="translateButon" Text="Translate" Clicked="OnTranslate" />
```

bound command in cs:

```
void OnTranslate (object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        translatedNumber = Core.PhonewordTranslator.ToNumber (phoneNumberText.Text);
        if (!string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace (translatedNumber)) {
            callButton.IsEnabled = true;
            callButton.Text = "Call " + translatedNumber;
        } else {
            callButton.IsEnabled = false;
            callButton.Text = "Call";
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Button is something like

```
Button b = new Button();
```

Then you should add a button to a layout

```
StackLayout SL = new StackLayout();
SL.Children.Add(b);
```

Then set your content page to stacklayout